# How can I use a relative cell reference in a data validation list in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Couldn't find an answer for this one. I'm basically using a data validation list to select between three options: a checkmark, a blank, and a formula.

In column B I have names, and in column C I have dates. The cells in columns D onwards are subject to the data validation rule. The formula is intended to identify the date found on the same row as the cell in question and add 6 months to it. I've been playing around, and the following is the closest I've gotten:

```
=EDATE((ADDRESS((ROW()), 3, 4)), 6)
```

However, this is giving me a #VALUE error, presumably because I'm not directly using a cell reference for the first part of the EDATE formula.

It's also worth noting that this document is live on Teams, which currently has macros disabled institutionally, so I can't use these.

Can anybody help me create a relative cell reference using this EDATE formula? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDATE wants the input as a date from DATE function, or as a result of another formula
Therefore add the INDIRECT function to get the content of the cell.

```
=EDATE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 3, 4)), 6)
```